# Virtualmin, mail format for usernames

Tags: virtualmin

I'm scripting to set up via cli commands my **template** settings on **Webmin version 1.660**.

I still miss to set the format for mail usernames.

System Settings -> Server Templates -> Mail for Domain -> Format for usernames that include domain

Here I want to setup **username@domain**, but on the cli I found nothing.

What I tried to do is getting the whole template settings, but I don't find this property:

```
$ virtualmin get-template --id 0 | grep mail
avail: dns=1 mail=1 web=1 webalizer=1 mysql=1 postgres=1 spam=1 file=1 passwd=1 proc=2 cron=1 at=1 telnet=1 updown=0 change-user=1 htaccess-htpasswd=1 mailboxes=1 custom=0 shell=0 webminlog=0 syslog=1 phpini=1 virtualmin-awstats=virtualmin-mailman
mail: 
mail_bcc: 
mail_cc: 
mail_on: none
mail_subject: Virtual server created
mailboxlimit: none
mailgroup: none
web_webmail: 1
web_webmaildom:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found there is no way to do that.